# Recursion with AngularJS ngRoute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've got some problem with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC App.

**Angular Script which is made by [Wilmer Saint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4775223/wilmer-saint):**

```
(function () {

var AAngScript = angular.module('AAngScript', ['ngRoute']);

/* some stuff */

function RegisterController ($location, RegistrationFactory) {

    // vm as in view-model
    var vm = this;

    vm.registerForm = {
        emailAdress: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        registrationFailure: false
    };

    vm.register = function () {
        var result = RegistrationFactory($scope.registerForm.emailAdress, $scope.registerForm.password, $scope.registerForm.confirmPassword);
        result.then(function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $location.path('/routeOne');
            } else {
                $scope.registerForm.registrationFailure = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
//some stuff

function RegistrationFactory($http, $q) {


    return function(emailAdress, password, rememberMe) {
        var deferredObject = $q.defer();

        $http.post(
            '/Account/Register', {
                Email: emailAdress,
                Password: password,
                ConfirmPassword: confirmPassword
            }
            ).
        success(function (data) {
            if (data == "True") {
                deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
            } else {
                deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
            }
        }).
        error(function () {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
        });

        return deferredObject.promise;
    }
};
//some stuff
})();
```

**Partial view _Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AAngScript">
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/AAngScript.js"></script>
...

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/#!/login">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#!/register">Register</a></li>
                </ul>

...

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <div ng-view></div>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Register.cshtml:**

```
<div class="row">
    <form ng-submit="register()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailAdress">Email</label>
            <input id="emailAdress" type="email" ng-model="registerForm.emailAdress" required pattern="{6,30}" autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.password" required pattern="{6,30}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
            <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.confirmPassword" required pattern="{6,30}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**There is the bad picture while I'm click reference "Register" or "Log In":**
[image]

And console many of `Error: too much recursion`

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Comment: I realised, that the problem is that `LoginController` called infinitely. But I don't know what to do with it.